# React-Rails Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a `handleFormSubmit` function on my `Appointments.jsx` file and define an object there to hold my `title` and `appointment_date` state.

`Appointements.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Appointment from './Appointment';
import AppointmentForm from './AppointmentForm';
import AppointmentsList from './AppointmentsList';

class Appointments extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
       appointments: this.props.appointments,
       title: 'Put your event title',
       appointment_date: 'When would this happen?'
    };

    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this)


   }

   handleUserInput(obj_value){
    this.setState(obj_value);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(){
    let apppointment = { 
      title: this.state.title, 
      appointment_date: this.state.appointment_date 
    };

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: '/appointments',
            data: { apppointment }, 
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data); 
            }
          });
  }


   render(){
     return(
      <div>
        <AppointmentForm title={this.state.title} 
         appointment_date={this.state.appointment_date} 
         onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
         onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
         />
        <AppointmentsList appointments={this.props.appointments} />
     </div>
     )
   }
}

export default Appointments;
```

I passed this function on my `AppointmentsForm.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';

class AppointmentForm extends React.Component{

    handleChange = e => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        const obj_value = {};
        obj_value[name] = e.target.value;
        this.props.onUserInput(obj_value);
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onFormSubmit();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>Make a new appointment</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input name='title' 
                     value={this.props.title} 
                     onChange={this.handleChange} />

                    <input name='appointment_date' 
                    value={this.props.appointment_date} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />

                    <input type='submit' value='Make Appointment' />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AppointmentForm;
```

I am expecting that my ajax code will submit this via post and will atleast put a console log as a success measure. Unfortunately I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Object.handleFormSubmit [as onFormSubmit] (Appointments.jsx:28)
    at AppointmentForm._this.handleSubmit (AppointmentForm.jsx:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:191)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:240)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:293)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:308)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:393)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:418)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3303)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3312)
handleFormSubmit @ Appointments.jsx:28
AppointmentForm._this.handleSubmit @ AppointmentForm.jsx:14
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:191
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:240
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:293
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:308
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:393
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:418
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3303
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3312
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3284
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3329
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3539
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3583
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21731
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:800
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3593
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4313
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4234
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:661
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11079
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21748
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:813
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4213
```

I did check my `title` inside my appointment object and is defined correctly.

I am wondering what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i'm guessing this issue is due to binding of this in handleSubmit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the binding of this for you `handlFormSubmit` function, either bind it in constructor

```
this.handlFormSubmit = this.handlFormSubmit.bind(this)
```

Or use arrow function

```
handlFormSubmit () => {
  // your code here
}
```

[`Demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-fztth)